# Are all sets in ZFC members of some set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My question is:
Are all sets (objects) in ZFC members of some other set? I mean is it true that:
$$ \forall x \exists y (x\in y)$$
If this were false, we would have sets that are not members of anything. Then how would they be different from a class in NBG?

Also, I'd appreciate it if you could introduce some resources that discuss NBG formally with a stress on syntax like Bourbaki's set theory.

Comment: You mean $x\in\mathcal P(x)$, or $x\in\{x\}$, or some other stuff like that? Also, why do you want Bourbaki style syntax, it is ***awful***.

Comment: Yes, in ZFC, every set is an element of another set; this follows from the Axiom of Pairs.

Comment: I don’t understand your question about “different from a class in NBG”. As I recall, in NBG, a class $x$ is a set if and only if there exists $y$ such that $x\in y$. Not everything in NBG is a set, but everything is a class. In ZFC, everything is a set; and anything you can describe in ZFC will be a set when translated in an NBG setting...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Is the following correct?:
A class is not a member of anything. So based on your answer, there are no classes among sets in ZFC. So we need to modify ZFC such that we end up with a language that has objects that are not member of anything and one such language is NBG.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It doesn't have to be Bourbaki syntax. What I meant is: A book that discusses the language of NBG like: 1 - these are the symbols, 2 - These are the rules for making objects and properties 3 - These are the axiom schemes and axioms that give you theorems.

Comment: @Ali: In ZF, everything is a set; you cannot speak about anything that is not a set, at least not within the theory. The primitive notions for ZF are "set" and "is an element of". The primitive notions in NBG are "classes" and "is an element of". Both "set" and "proper class" are *defined* terms in NBG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Axiom of Pairing is an Axiom of ZF. It states
$$\forall A\forall B\exists C\forall D\Bigr( D\in C\longleftrightarrow (D=A\vee D=B)\Bigl).$$
In particular, every set is an element of another set, since given any $A$ there exists $C$ such that $C=\{A\}$.

Alternatively, you can use the Axiom of the Power Set; we have
$$\forall A\exists B\forall C\Bigl(C\in B\longleftrightarrow(\forall x(x\in C\rightarrow x\in A)\Bigr).$$
which gives $A\in B$, since $A$ satisfies $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow x\in A)$.

Comment: If you're using Power Set, then you're overdoing it. $A\in\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yeah, I was just thinking that...